# How to display pandas pivot table as seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I've imported a CSV file in to a data frame and created a pivot table:

```
            Amount
Date              
2018-09-30     222
2018-10-01     105
2018-10-02      32
2018-10-03     155
2018-10-04     156
```

How do I plot this as a bar graph? trying to use this but it gives me errors:

```
sns.barplot(x="Date", y="Amount", Data=Tx_Data)
```

Could not interpret input 'Date'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Date is not a column but an index. Try

```
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y="Amount", data=df)
```

Comment: That worked! You may be able to tell I'm very new to python. Any recommendations for youtube series on pandas or seaborn?

Comment: I would start with a book, try Python for data analysis by Wes McKinney?

Comment: Got the book :) after finishing with Pandas I'm also want to be able to graphically display the data. Any book recommendations for seaborn?